# numerical dispersion in ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving an ODE equation : $u_{xx}+k^2u=0$. I use second order approximation to the $u_{xx}$.The exact solution is $\exp(ikx)$, where $k$ is the wavenumber. For the boundary condition I set $u(0) = \exp(ik0) = 1$ and I use $u_x-iku=0$ when $x=2\pi$.

I plotted the graph with Matlab and saw some phase shifting. As my $k$ increases, the phase shifting also increases.

But my scheme does not include time. Why does it still have shifting?

Comment: You should add some more details about how you solve the system. Why do you think "time" has to be a factor to get shifting? To a numerical scheme there is no such thing as "time" and "space" - they are just a coordinate like any other.

Comment: I set N nodal points in the domain [0,2pi], I solve the solution at each nodal point using the eqt u(n+1)-2u(n)+u(n-1)/h^2 , where h is the mesh step. At the last nodal point, I use the equation u(N+1)-u(N-1)/2h=u(N) and I let u(N+1)=u(1). Then I set up a system of linear equation to solve u(1)-u(N).

Comment: I know time and space are just two variable in the scheme. But I do remember for a fully discrete scheme, there is a dispersion relation. I am thinking maybe this is why phase shifting exist. I don't quite understand the definition of phase shifting. Do it mean the graph shift horizontally as time increases?

Comment: The linear system here can be solved in closed form and shown to converge to the true solution $e^{ikx}$ when $N\to \infty$. The numerical solution depends on the parameter $\epsilon = \frac{2\pi k}{N}$. We need $\epsilon \ll 1$ to be sure to be close to the true solution. If you get a solution that is "phase shifted" wrt the true solution then you are likely using a way to small $N$, i.e. $\epsilon$ being too large.